# error using minfi package to load IDAT data, invalid n argument, BiocParallel errors

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm trying to load IDATs using the bioconductor minfi package, but iam coming across the below unfamiliar error when I use read.metharray.exp function. beloaw are my all script.

library(minfi)

baseDir <- "D:/Projects/methylation profiling/GSE172464"

list.files(baseDir)

[1] "GSE172464_PTSDtwins_samplesheet.csv"     "GSE172464_PTSDtwins_samplesheet.xlsx"

[3] "GSM5257464_202060330061_R01C01_Grn.idat" "GSM5257464_202060330061_R01C01_Red.idat"

[5] "GSM5257465_202060330061_R02C01_Grn.idat" "GSM5257465_202060330061_R02C01_Red.idat"

[7] "GSM5257466_202060330061_R08C01_Grn.idat" "GSM5257466_202060330061_R08C01_Red.idat"

[9] "GSM5257467_202060330061_R07C01_Grn.idat" "GSM5257467_202060330061_R07C01_Red.idat"

[11] "GSM5257468_202060330062_R03C01_Grn.idat" "GSM5257468_202060330062_R03C01_Red.idat"

[13] "GSM5257469_202060330062_R04C01_Grn.idat" "GSM5257469_202060330062_R04C01_Red.idat"

[15] "GSM5257470_202060330062_R05C01_Grn.idat" "GSM5257470_202060330062_R05C01_Red.idat"

[17] "GSM5257471_202060330062_R06C01_Grn.idat" "GSM5257471_202060330062_R06C01_Red.idat"

[19] "GSM5257472_202060330095_R01C01_Grn.idat" "GSM5257472_202060330095_R01C01_Red.idat"

[21] "GSM5257473_202060330095_R02C01_Grn.idat" "GSM5257473_202060330095_R02C01_Red.idat"

[23] "GSM5257474_202060330095_R06C01_Grn.idat" "GSM5257474_202060330095_R06C01_Red.idat"

[25] "GSM5257475_202060330095_R05C01_Grn.idat" "GSM5257475_202060330095_R05C01_Red.idat"

### read target

targets <- read.metharray.sheet("GSE172464_PTSDtwins_samplesheet.csv", base = baseDir)

View(targets)

[read.metharray.sheet] Found the following CSV files:

[1] "D:/Projects/methylation profiling/GSE172464/GSE172464_PTSDtwins_samplesheet.csv"

target$Basename

[1] "D:/Projects/PTSD/methylation profiling/GSE172464/GSM5257464_202060330061_R01C01"

[2] "D:/Projects/PTSD/methylation profiling/GSE172464/GSM5257465_202060330061_R02C01"

[3] "D:/Projects/PTSD/methylation profiling/GSE172464/GSM5257466_202060330061_R08C01"

[4] "D:/Projects/PTSD/methylation profiling/GSE172464/GSM5257467_202060330061_R07C01"

[5] "D:/Projects/PTSD/methylation profiling/GSE172464/GSM5257468_202060330062_R03C01"

[6] "D:/Projects/PTSD/methylation profiling/GSE172464/GSM5257469_202060330062_R04C01"

[7] "D:/Projects/PTSD/methylation profiling/GSE172464/GSM5257470_202060330062_R05C01"

[8] "D:/Projects/PTSD/methylation profiling/GSE172464/GSM5257471_202060330062_R06C01"

[9] "D:/Projects/PTSD/methylation profiling/GSE172464/GSM5257472_202060330095_R01C01"

[10] "D:/Projects/PTSD/methylation profiling/GSE172464/GSM5257473_202060330095_R02C01"

[11] "D:/Projects/PTSD/methylation profiling/GSE172464/GSM5257474_202060330095_R06C01"

[12] "D:/Projects/PTSD/methylation profiling/GSE172464/GSM5257475_202060330095_R05C01"

### read IDAT data

RGset <- read.metharray.exp(base = baseDir, targets = targets)

Error: BiocParallel errors

element index: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...

first error: invalid 'n' argument

Timing stopped at: 0.25 0.02 0.39

I am a beginner in R and I don't know how can I resolve this error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: well, I exactly want to load IDAT file of methylation array EPIC (850k) in R. I use minfi package to load targets and  IDAT file.  but when i try to load data with read.metharray.exp function i got an unfamiliar error from BiocParallel package. i think may there is a problem at the downloading IDAT file , and i try to downloaded data again But the problem was not solved. ERROR: Error: BiocParallel errors

element index: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...

first error: invalid 'n' argument

Timing stopped at: 0.25 0.02 0.39